Is this sentence correct and if not would you correct it?
Odio las personas quien non tienen gratitud a ellos.

It would be great if you could say it in English. As written in Spanish, its meaning is not clear.

¿Odio a las personas que no tienen gratitud? ¿Odio a las personas desagradecidas? "Non" no se usa en el español actual, suena medieval. Como indica Gustavson, no está claro el significado, sobre todo esa parte de "a ellos".

The sentence is not correct, but without knowing what you want to say, we have no way to correct it.

Al decir ‘a ellos’ el interlocutor estaba refiriendo a los soldados que luchan para un país cualquiera.

Ya que no conocemos aquellas personas no es apropiado poner el verbo ‘tener’ en el subjuntivo?

@WuncieAdams You can edit the question to add that information about "a ellos" being the army. I think that it's very relevant for understanding the context and what you want to convey.


Odio las personas quien non tienen gratitud a ellos.

El verbo odiar es transitivo. Cuando el complemento directo se refiere a una persona o a varias, en español se introducen usando la preposición "a".
Como te indicaba en un comentario, "non" ya no se usa en el español actual, suena arcaico, de tiempos medievales, en su lugar empleamos "no".
La gratitud es un sentimiento que se siente (sentir) o se muestra (mostrar) más que se tiene. Para mí resulta más idiomático usar uno de esos dos verbos en lugar de tener.
Como indica user37164, "people" puede traducirse indistintamente como "gente" o "personas".
Aplicando todo lo dicho arriba, y una vez sabemos que "a ellos" se refiere a las Fuerzas Armadas de un país, permíteme ofrecerte otras versiones que son más idiomáticas

Odio a las personas que no sienten gratitud hacia ellos
Odio a la gente que no siente gratitud hacia ellos
Odio a las personas que no muestran gratitud hacia ellos
Odio a las personas que no les muestran gratitud
Odio a la gente que no les agradece su servicio

Esta última contiene más información implícita, con ella no sería tan necesaria la aclaración de quienes son ellos.

muchísimas gracias a usted por haberme explicado mis errores y por las sugerencias de frases más adecuadas que mi frase inicial. Si respondo tan paulatinamente es que hoy es la primera vez que haya visto su respuesta. No visito stackexchange a menudo porque muchas veces es difícil formular una oración que sea aprobado de stackexchange.

@WuncieAdams De nada. Me alegro de haberte ayudado :-)

If you want to say "I hate people who have no gratitude for them." then it should be "Odio a la gente que no tiene gratitud por ellos.".

The problem is that we do not know what the OP wants the sentence to mean.

@mdewey OP has added extra information in the comments. It seems that the sentence refers to people not being grateful with their country's army.
